# How to Read Azure File Share Files from Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-storage, azure-pipelines, azure-files

I currently have created an Azure storage account. Inside of this storage, I've created two file shares. I've uploaded files into each file share, and would like to access these files from within the Azure DevOps pipeline.

I've researched online how to do this, and have not found a resource detailing how to do this. Has anyone done this before? If yes, what are the steps to read file share files from an azure devOps pipeline?

Thanks.

People asked

Comment: No need for the passive-aggressive statements, as it doesn't resolve the issue, only creates tension and makes you look bad in the community.

Comment: The question is fine, because in this case you can't write code, when you can't figure out which way to solve the problem. By the way: I had exactly the same question in my mind today. Thanks for this question and the answers (-:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution using the [Microsoft Azure File Share Storage Client Library for Python](https://pypi.org/project/azure-storage-file-share/). I ran the following steps inside of my Azure pipeline to connect to my File Share. Below is an example that connects to the file share and shares all its contents:

```
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      displayName: 'Set Python 3.8.3'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 3.8.3
        addToPath: true
      name: pyTools

    - script: $(pyTools.pythonLocation)/bin/pip3 install azure-storage-file-share
      displayName: Install azure-storage-file-share module
        
    - task: PythonScript@0
      displayName: Show files and directories inside of File Share
      inputs:
        scriptSource: 'inline'
        script: |
          import platform
          from azure.storage.fileshare import ShareDirectoryClient

          connection_string = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<storage-name>;AccountKey=<access-key>==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
          parent_dir = ShareDirectoryClient.from_connection_string(conn_str=connection_string, share_name=<file-share-name>, directory_path="")

          my_list = list(parent_dir.list_directories_and_files())
          print(my_list)
          print(platform.python_version()
```

Answer (score 3):

> would like to access these files from within the Azure DevOps pipeline

You could try to use **AzCopy command** to copy/download those two file shares from Azure blob to Azure DevOps Pipeline:

```
azcopy login
azcopy copy /Source:https://myaccount.file.core.windows.net/myfileshare/myfolder/ /Dest:$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\myfolder
```

You can find more info in this document:

[Quickstart: Upload, download, and list blobs with PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-powershell#upload-blobs-to-the-container)

Comment: Thanks Leo. Will check out this resource.