# Can we copy data from azure file share to azure artifacts

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

Is it possible to copy files from Azure files shares to azure artifacts using build pipeline task?

Comment: Hi You can copy files from azure files to azure artifacts, you just need to download them in your pipeline first and then publish to the azure artifacts. See below answer of @Krzysztof Madej. You can [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. What you need is actually download files for Azure Files and publish them to Azure Artifacts. Please check [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62939267/how-to-read-azure-file-share-files-from-azure-devops-pipeline) where is shown a way how to download files from Azure Files.

Azure Artifacts is a package feed and thus it depends what kind of package you want to publish, so confoguration may differ. But if you want to publish this as [build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops)/[pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops) artofacts you may simply use regular tasks.